# JSON file reading by Django

Tags: python, json, django, postgresql, scrapy

I have a json file of the following format which is generated by scrapy:

```
[
    {
        "area_of_interest": [
            "Pharmaceutical"
        ], 
        "department": [
            "RETAIL PHARMACY: APOTHECARY"
        ], 
        "duties": [
            "EDUCATION:"
        ], 
        "job_function": [
            "Texas Health Presbyterian Hospital Dallas is seeking a Registered Pharmacy Technician to work PRN (as needed) hours in the Retail Pharmacy. Primary hours will be weekday shifts between 9a-5p. There will be occasional 12 hr shifts. The following is required:"
        ], 
        "job_id": [
            "  56345"
        ], 
        "job_type": [
            "PRN"
        ], 
        "location": [
            "Dallas, TX, US"
        ], 
        "location_type": [
            " Texas Health Dallas"
        ], 
        "relocation": [
            "No"
        ], 
        "shift": [
            "Variable"
        ], 
        "speciality": [
            "TCH"
        ], 
        "title": [
            "Pharmacy Tech (PRN) - Retail Pharmacy"
        ], 
        "travel": [
            "NN"
        ]
    },...
```

This is how my model looks:

```
class health(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    location_type = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    job_id = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    area_of_interest = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    job_type = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    shift = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    relocation = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    travel = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    speciality = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    job_function = models.CharField(max_length=96)
    duties = models.CharField(max_length=56)
```

As i am new to Django, I was referring to many posts and blogs on how to read a json file from django and store the data into a postgresql database. But most of the posts were related to javascript which i do not know how to use.

So my question is, how do i read the data from the json file and store the fields into a postgresql database using django?

Thank you in advance

Comment: How do you get the json to django? How do you get the json anyway?

Comment: The json is being generated from a scrapy script. All i need django to do is read this json file and store it in a postgresql. I do not get the file to django. The json file is just saved into the scrapy project in the home folder. All i want django to do is access this file from else where to save the data in the database. Can it be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See doc of build-in [json](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module for reference how to parse json and see [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_create) for reference how to create do batch inserts

Sample code (untested):

```
# Read file 
f = open('path_to_file.json')
json_string = f.read()
f.close()

# Convert json string to python object
import json
data = json.loads(json_string)

# Create model instances for each item
items = []
for item in data:
   # create model instances...
   item = YourModel(*item)
   items.append(item)

# Create all in one query
YourModel.objects.bulk_create(items)
```